# Javascript : how to add a new element to the array that has key value pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array say `a[0]` which already has it's own key value pairs. Now I'd like to another element to the array a which would be `a[1]` and add a property to it.

I'd like to add key value pairs to that newly added property to `a[1]`.

Ex : `a[1]` now has say `address`.
     Now I want to add key value pairs such as

```
"street" : "Avenue St"
"pin" : "560064"
```

And then I want to add another key-value pair say "city" : "Tokyo"

Finally it must look like :

```
address : {
   "street" : "Avenue St"
   "pin" : "560064"
}
city : "Tokyo"
```

And this should be for the same array index : a[1].

How do I do this?

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: If your `a[1]` already has "address" in it, you can do `a[1].address = {"street" : "Avenue St", "pin" : "560064"};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following way:

```js
var a = [{name: "John"},{address: "Old Avenue St"}];
a[1].address = {"street" : "Avenue St", "pin" : "560064"};

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but a little change I've added to the question. Sorry for that

Comment: @AravindS, you are most welcome...you can add next object in the similar way in the next index like `a[2] = { city : "Tokyo"} `......thanks

Comment: Ya, got it, but the solution should be like the city needs to be added to a[1] which now contains both address and city properties. I got it nevertheless. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use push , using index will may cause unwanted issues, as you need to remember / calculate size of array every-time.

```js
var a = [{name: "John"}];
a.push({ address: {"street" : "Avenue St", "pin" : "560064"} });

console.log(a);
```